# proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm using [proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) to validate my custom form requests but it does not work with me, it gives `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` . Searched a lot about the problem even in its documentation but could not find it. Any help is appreciated.

```
//app view
@include('partials.nav')
@include('errors.errors')
@yield('content')

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Laravel Javascript Validation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
```

My form to be validated

```
//Upload Form
{!! Form::model($paper, ['method' => 'POST', 'id' =>'uploadPaper',  'action' => ['PaperController@papershow', $paper->id], 'files' => true]) !!}    

       @include('partials._paperForm',['submitBtn' => 'Show Paper Details'])

   {!! Form::close() !!}

   <!-- Laravel Javascript Validation -->
   {!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\PaperRequest'); !!}
```

My custom request:

```
//App\Http\Requests\PaperRequest
public function rules()
{
    return [ 'title'=> 'required|min:10',
                'type' => 'required',
                'keywords'=> 'required|min:10',
                'abstract'=> 'required|min:50',
                'dept_name' => 'required|min:3',
                'file'  =>  'required|mimes:pdf|max:10000',];}
```

Comment: This error usually shows up when jQuery has been loaded after the library that is depending on it. Are you certain you're loading jQuery before the validation script or are there any issues with loading jQuery you see in the javascript console?

Comment: Ops! Yes this was the problem, I was loading the library just after the jQuery :D.. the problem solved.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Easy mistake, I've done it many times. Glad it's working for you now!

Comment: Yes really, same thing for me, I made this stupid mistake many times and I don't know why I was so sure that I'm calling the library before using it :D

Comment: Working too hard perhaps? Or maybe you need some coffee =] Would appreciate if you can accept the answer in case anyone else comes across the question

Comment: Oh btw, thanks for introducing me to this validation library - I didn't know it existed going to try it out!

Comment: hahaha, when working on different projects together this is happening :-D

Comment: Yes actually this is one of the greatest JS validations for Laravel, now it is working very well in a very nice way.. And it is so easy no need to rebuilt your tags and roles since it takes from laravel's own roles.

Comment: Awesome! Great to hear it's working well for you. I have some huge forms to put validation for so I think this is going to work great as the client validation will be so much easier now. Laravel and the packages developed for it keep getting better and better. Again, many thanks!

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless the question is about [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are loading jQuery before you load the `validation.js` which depends on it.

From docs:

> This package also depends of jQuery, but it's not bundled into
>   provided script, you have to include manually
>
> To use this package you muts include jQuery and before the provided
>   public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js script

https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/wiki/Dependencies